# How does Heroku's charging model work for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I really can't make any sense of Heroku's offer. If for example, I create a Rails app, and I want to upload it to Heroku, do I need to pay something? I would like to provide the client something he could play with, but I don't know if I need web dynos or worker dynos just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku has a free offer. So if you don't pay, you have one dyno and can use it.

Very simple to test without big traffic.

The difference between dyno and worker is a dyno is use to web rendering and worker to background job.

Comment: How much traffic can one dyno handle?

Comment: Depend of your code. By example if you avg response is 1 second, you can't have more than 1 request by seconde. If you have response of 1ms, you can have 100request by seconde.

Answer (score 3):

Read the DevCenter - there's not much to take in..

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3